# Possible causes for automatically generated Delete command for GridView not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I have a GridView and a SqlDataSource, which I have set to automatically generate Delete/Insert/Update statements. I then just enabled Deleting on the GridView, and usually away I'd go. For some reason though, the row is not being deleted - the page is posting back but the row is still there. When Delete is clicked, RowDeleting does fire though.

What possible causes could this be?

Edit: SELECT command:

```
SELECT id, templatename, CASE WHEN type = 'W' THEN 'Weekly' WHEN type = 'M' THEN 'Monthly' WHEN type = 'Q' THEN 'Quarterly' WHEN type = 'S' THEN 'Six-monthly' WHEN type = 'A' THEN 'Anually' END AS TypeText, CASE WHEN invorcred = 'I' THEN 'Invoice' WHEN invorcred = 'C' THEN 'Credit' END AS 'InvOrCredText', nextinvdate, lastinvdate FROM InvoiceTemplates WHERE (sageaccount = @sageaccount)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write in the RowDeleting event instead of auto generated, maybe because you need to get the id of the row you want to delete (Where clause)

Example:
Label13 is Hidden, I get it from select statement but I don't show it the user.
VB.NET:

```
    Protected Sub gvAddresses_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gvAddresses.RowDeleting

        Dim selectedAddessId As Label = gvAddresses.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Label13")
        SqlDataSource.DeleteParameters("add_id").DefaultValue = selectedAddessId.Text
        SqlDataSource.Delete()
End Sub
```

C#

```
    protected void gvAddresses_RowDeleting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the address Id to delete the selected address only
    Label selectedAddessId = gvAddresses.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Label13");
    SqlDataSource.DeleteParameters("add_id").DefaultValue = selectedAddessId.Text;
    SqlDataSource.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the delete column to a template field. There is a known bug for the delete command in combination with imagebuttons.

Comment: I've tried that and sadly still nothing. Also I believe it's just using a LinkButton

Answer (score 0):

Try see which SQL statement has been executed on DB.
(You can use for this purpose the "SQL Server Profiler" utility)

Answer (score 0):

Do you return data from multiple tables in database? If your sqldatasource's select command, selects data from more than one table, I think the delete command would not work.

Comment: No, but that's a point. Something I am always changing is the SELECT command, but it's all from one table. I'll update the post with this.

Comment: Tried with just the bog standard select generated and still doesn't work :(